# CannotCreateContainerError: too many colons in address

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, terraform

I'm trying to set up a `fluentd` logging container on ECS. I have a task definition which (truncated) looks like this:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "ecs_tooling_task_definition" {
  family = "${var.environment}-ecs_tooling_task_definition"

  container_definitions = <<DEFINITION
    [
            {
                "name": "tooling",
                "image": "myimage.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/tooling:latest",
                "essential": true,
                "memory": 512,
                "cpu": 10,
                "portMappings": [
                    {
                        "containerPort": 24224,
                        "hostPort": 24224
                    }
                ],
                "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "fluentd",
                "options": {
                    "fluentd-address":"https://fluentd-url:9090"
                }
              }
          }
        ]
DEFINITION
}
```

When trying to start the container it gives me this error:

```
CannotCreateContainerError: API error (400): invalid fluentd-address fluentd-url:9090: 
address fluentd-url:9090: too many colons in address
```

This is because somewhere along the line it's adding a colon onto the end of the address.

[I've looked at the Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/fluentd/#options) and also the [AWS Task Definition docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html) which pointed me towards `fluentd-address` and there is no parameter for port.

What's going on? I'd hate to have to set this up using the console.

Comment: Use `log-opts`? https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/fluentd/#usage

Comment: The above is a shot in the dark without the rest of the code.

Comment: `log-opts` is what `options` is for an AWS task definition. What rest of the code are you looking for? I've added the rest of the task definition

Comment: I ran your exact definition except change the image to `"image":"alpine:latest"` and it created successfully. 
Terraform v0.11.2
+ provider.aws v1.18.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `https://` in front of the `fluentd-address` solved this for me:

```
"fluentd-address":"https://fluentd-url:9090"
```

to

```
"fluentd-address":"fluentd-url:9090"
```